# What happens if you answered your own bountied question, and the bounty expires?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

What happens if I answered my own bounty, and no one else's answer fit my question?

When the bounty expires, I can't award it to anyone. What will happen?

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185637/147247

Comment: You will not get back your bounty **in any case**.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Please do not vote to close as duplicate without editing the community wiki to include this content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't award your bounty to yourself. If you don't award it to anyone else it will be lost or half the bounty goes to the highest upvoted answer if it has a score of 2+.

In any case - you will never get back your bounty or parts of it.